# Корректно добавить вызов статичной функции в существующий код smali

Tags: android, smali, dalvik

Я пытался добавить вызов публичной статичной функции из другого класса в код уже существующего метода на smali, который выглядел изначально так:

```
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .registers 1

    invoke-direct {p0}, Landroid/ext/ar;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method
```

после изменения:

```
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .registers 3

    move-object v0, p0

    move-object v1, v0

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Landroid/app/Activity;->getApplicationContext()Landroid/content/Context;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-static {v1}, Lcom/a/test/act;->Start(Landroid/content/Context;)V

    invoke-direct {p0}, Landroid/ext/ar;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method
```

Но после этого приложение попросту зависает, даже не выпоняя метод Start и не переходит к выполнению другого. Как это сделать правильно, чтобы работало? Почему не работает?

Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Не знаю насколько это критично для байт-кода, но лучше не выполнять никаких действий с объектом до вызова супер-конструктора. Однозначно могу сказать, что в конструкторе наследника `Activity` этот код не уместен - `getApplicationContext()` вернёт `null`, так как активность в этом моменте не привязана к контексту.

Comment: Спасибо, понятно, буду пробовать

Comment: Спасибо, это реально мне помогло!